# Can Nagios monitor a service only by hostname?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, nagios, failover

I have two hosts `server1` and `server2` where I do manual fail over. The C record `master-server` then points to the one which is the master. Only the master host should have a certain service checked.

It seams that Nagios needs the IP address and hostname to check a service, which is a problem in this case, as the IP of `master-server` can be either the IP's of `server1` or `server2`.

**Question**

Is there a way not to specify an IP address for a Nagios service check?

Comment: You should monitor both individual servers *and* the Virtual IP. 

Oh, and you should also monitor your DNS server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your DNS works you can just as well specify the hostname (FQDN) in Nagios, no need to go by IP address. Nagios just needs to be able to resolve the hostname (FQDN) correctly, which should be a given.

Answer (score 4):

The `address` of a host can be *absolutely anything*, as long as the plugin knows how to handle it. Examples and documentation typically use IP addresses, to remove DNS as a failure point in the monitoring process.

You can certainly use the hostname of your manual failover setup, but you might run into DNS caching problems. A better method would be to use [check_multi](http://my-plugin.de/wiki/projects/check_multi/start).

For example, you could have it return OK when exactly 1 service is OK, CRITICAL if neither is OK, and WARNING if both are somehow OK.